# Unity toggling turns off the menu that it's toggling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a toggle in Unity, here is the code:

```
public GameObject startToggle;
bool startToggled = true;

public void Toggle()
{
    if (startToggled == false)
    {
        startToggle.SetActive(true);
        startToggled = true;
    }

    if (startToggled == true)
    {
        startToggle.SetActive(false);
        startToggled = false;
    }
}
```

If does the method (as debug logs have proven), but on the screen it just turns off the menu that it's toggling and it doesn't toggle afterwards.

Comment: Em, maybe you should change last `if` to `else if`? I guess it will turn state to `true` at first `if` and then next `if` will turn it back to `false` in one run? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you follow your logic, if `startToggled` is false, you then set it to true. Immediately after that, you check to see if `startToggled` is true, and your code then sets it to false. The effect is that the menu will toggle on, then off again in the same frame.

One possible fix looks like this:

```
public void Toggle()
{
    // flip startToggled
    startToggled != startToggled;
    startToggle.SetActive(startToggled);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That #### really bugged me out last night